# SQL Server Connection error: Setting IsolationLevel to ReadCommitted is not supported

Tags: sql-server, mule, anypoint-studio, sql-server-administration

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server from Anypoint Studio but I'm getting following error:

[image: Error Message]

This is the connection string which I'm using:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://adwdmzdw1.database.windows.net;DatabaseName=adwdmzdw1;user=*****;password=**********
```

Thank you

Comment: It's [Azure] SQL Database and  ot SQL Server Database Engine [on premise]. Try to use SQL Server Management Studio or try to disable (within Anypoint Studio) Read Committed isolation level. SQL Database is using ReadCommited Snapshot isolation level. / https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/12/26/be-aware-of-the-difference-in-isolation-levels-if-porting-an-application-from-windows-azure-sql-db-to-sql-server-in-windows-azure-virtual-machine/

Comment: Hitesh --- do you realize that the credentials to your account are exposed?  Password's in your preview, and user name was in your original post.  I changed the user name to make it less obvious, but it's in the history.  Change your password ASAP.  Be more careful next time.